# Magento 2.3. - Show fullpath in breadcrumb on product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, breadcrumbs

Is there any workaround to show the fullpath with category and subcategories in the breadcrumb on the product detail page?

It now only shows: Home > Product "myproduct"

Answer (score 4):

Module Method Working For me in Magento 2.1 / 2.2 /2.3 :: Show Fullpath in BreadCrumb On Product Detail Page(Home > Category1 > Category2 > MyProduct).Also Works on MegaMenu

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName_ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName_ModuleName]" setup_version="0.1.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="[VendorName_ModuleName]_product_breadcrumbs" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/Product/View.php

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View as MagentoView;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class View
{

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $product;
    /**
     * @var StoreManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $collection;
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $resultPage;


    /**
     * View constructor.
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param PageFactory $resultPage
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManager $storeManager,
        Registry $registry,
        Collection $collection,
        PageFactory $resultPage)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->resultPage = $resultPage;
    }

    public function afterExecute(MagentoView $subject, $result)
    {
        if(!$result instanceof Page){
            return $result;
        }

        $resultPage = $this->resultPage->create();
        $breadcrumbsBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        if(!$breadcrumbsBlock || !isset($breadcrumbsBlock)){
            return $result;

        }
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'home',
            [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                'link' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
            ]
        );

        try {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $result;
        }
        
        $pageMainTitle = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
        if ($pageMainTitle) {
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
        }

        if(null == $product->getCategory() || null == $product->getCategory()->getPath()){
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'cms_page',
                [
                    'label' => $product->getName(),
                    'title' => $product->getName(),
                ]
            );
            return $result;
        }

        $categories = $product->getCategory()->getPath();
        $categoriesids = explode('/', $categories);

        $categoriesCollection = null;
        try {
            $categoriesCollection = $this->collection
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $categoriesids))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('include_in_menu')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $result;
        }

        foreach ($categoriesCollection->getItems() as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive() && $category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
                $categoryId = $category->getId();
                $path = [
                    'label' => $category->getName(),
                    'link' => $category->getUrl() ? $category->getUrl() : ''
                ];
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb('category' . $categoryId, $path);
            }
        }

        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'cms_page',
            [
                'label' => $product->getName(),
                'title' => $product->getName(),
            ]
        );

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');

            if (!$this->product->getId()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Failed to initialize product'));
            }
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

5.app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it worked for me when adding the `di.xml` in the `/etc/frontend/` directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, It was a typing mistake. I updated my answer now.

Comment: Thank you. It worked version 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento shows the breadcrumbs on the basis of the path from where the user arrives at the product/category page.

Suppose, a **product X** has been assigned to:

- **Category A**
- **Category A** >> **Subcategory B**

If the user reaches at the product by navigating through **Category A** only, then the breadcrumbs will show like:

- **Home** >> **Category A** >> **product X**

If the user reaches at the product by navigating through **Category A**, then **Subcategory B**, then the breadcrumbs will show like:

- **Home** >> **Category A** >> **Subcategory B** >> **product X**

and if the user reaches at the product by searching, the breadcrumbs will look like:

- **Home** >> **product X**

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I know it. I am using a 3rd party extension (megamenu). I think, there are not using the default navigation, therefore Magento2 doesnt display the categories.

Answer (score 0):

-If you are using some extra module like megamenu. In this case just replace your block  with this.

```
<?php

namespace VenorName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
class Crumbs extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $catalogData = null;

    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $catalogData,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        $evercrumbs = array();

        $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
            'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
        );
    
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    
        $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
        $categoryCollection->clear();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
        $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
        $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
        foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
            $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $category->getName(),
                'title' => $category->getName(),
                'link' => $category->getUrl()
            );
        }
    
        $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $product->getName(),
                'title' => $product->getName(),
                'link' => ''
            );
    
        return $evercrumbs;
}
}
```