# magento 2.3 now showing category and subcategory in breadcrum on prodcut detail page

Tags: magento2.3, breadcrumbs, product-detail-page

my product details page has url structure like

**url > cat > sub cat > product name**

but in breadcrumb i see only **home > product name** i want to show category and sub category also

**breadcrum.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
/** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs $block */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');

?>  
        <div class="ui breadcrumb" data-mage-init='{
            "breadcrumbs": {
                "categoryUrlSuffix": "<?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getCategoryUrlSuffix()); ?>",
                "useCategoryPathInUrl": <?= (int)$viewModel->isCategoryUsedInProductUrl(); ?>,
                "product": "<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->escapeJsQuote($viewModel->getProductName(), '"')); ?>"
            }
        }'>
        </div>
```

**layout.xml file**

```
 <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/breadcrumbs2.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Please follow this link upvote if issue get solved.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/295067/83578

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module for display category and subcategory in breadcrum on prodcut detail page

https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

You can use below reference URL for display category and subcategory in breadcrumbs on the product detail page:

[Magento 2.3. - Show fullpath in breadcrumb on product detail page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257531/magento-2-3-show-fullpath-in-breadcrumb-on-product-detail-page)

**OR**

As Sanket posted you can use below module:

https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb